# How to store unicode in a Go struct (golang)

Tags: go

I am reading in unicode names in golang.   My struct item is of type string, but this not correct I believe.

Is there an example of how to properly store unicode strings in a golang struct?

When I read the CSV document using csv.NewReader and print it to screen it works fine, but once in the struct as a string, it no longer prints correctly.  This seems like a simple byte / string issue but I am having a hard time resolving it.

I tried using []byte in the struct, but then how do I do comparisons of the strings laters and what is the way I would print that []byte to a file correctly?  Since I am writing to file as RDF, I suspect I need to convert to UTF-8 or something?

Answer (score 3):

Go expects string data to be encoded as UTF-8. If your input data uses a different encoding, you will need to convert it to UTF-8 before assigning it to a string.

You can do this manually, or use a third party library like [go-charset](https://code.google.com/p/go-charset/)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by "unicode". Everything in Go is expected to be UTF-8, including the `string` datatype, so there's probably nothing you need to do (as long as you're dealing with UTF-8).

`[]byte` is just a series of bytes. It opaque to the data that's in it. You don't need to do anything special to write it to a file.

The stdlib has the [`unicode`](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/), [`unicode/utf8`](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/), and [`unicode/utf16`](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf16/) packages. There's also a normalization package if you need it here: http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm

This blog post can explain it in more depth than we can answer here, and has some links to more resources: http://blog.golang.org/strings

Comment: In addition to the excellent blog post mentioned, I'd also recommend reading the [Text normalization in Go](https://blog.golang.org/normalization) article.